# Is there a simple way to generate a section of UI from an uploaded dataset?

Tags: r, shiny

I am setting up a shiny application that asks for a dataset, asks for information about said data set, and then runs a series of analytic models on said data set, taking into account information about the dataset (for example, the names of variables to adjust for in a regression). The app starts with a simple UI with a data upload input. Once the user has uploaded their data, I would like the UI to dynamically add a new section that asks the user to select a subset of variables from the column labels of their dataset.

I am working with RStudio Server via a Linux AWS machine.

My app is generated as an add-on to another R package that serves as a wrapper for most of the statistical functions I require. Since the app is quite large, the UI is composed of some standard text and a series of functions that call tabItems for the UI.

In the example below, the UI has a standard data upload user input. In addition to this I have attempted to use shiny::renderUI on the server side to take the user-provided dataset, read the columns, and return the set of columns via shiny::varSelectInput(). Unfortunately, my app does not provide this new input after uploading the data.

```
ui_data_1 <- function(){

y<-tabItem(tabName = "load_dat",
  shiny::tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
      # Data upload ---- -
      h2("Data"),
      p("Please upload your data file"),
      shiny::fileInput(
        inputId = "data_file", label = "Upload patient data file (.csv Only)",
        accept = c(".csv")
      ),
      h2("Treatment"),
    p("Instructions for treatment"),
    shiny::uiOutput("variables"))
)
)
return(y)
}   


server_data_1 <- function(){

 y <- shiny::renderUI({
 inFile <- input$data_file

 # Load data
 if (is.null(inFile)) {
   df <- shiny::reactive({NULL})
 } else {
   df <-  shiny::reactive({read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)})
 }

 varnames <- colnames(df())

 shiny::varSelectInput(
   inputId = "treat",
   label = "Treatment Variable",
   data = c(varnames)
 )
})
return(y)
}

#UI.R
body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
     ui_data_1()
)
ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "black")

#Server.R
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$variables  <- server_data_1()
}



shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app loads properly, as does the data upload menu. When I upload the data, I receive a notification indicating that the upload was successful. The label associated with inputId = "treat" is visible the entire time. However, the variable selection menu does not populate after uploading the data as expected. Perhaps I've done something wrong. Thanks in advance for any advice.